# How to get multiple selected checkbox in listView in windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I have developed a Windows 8.1 app using C#. Now I have created a textblock, when a user taps on it, I am opening a flyout which contains ListView with selectionMode as Multiple. Now, the listview data template contains CheckBox,which I am showing to user, but I don't know how to get multiple checkBox selected by user and populate all the selected items by comma seperated. My Data Template for ListView is below

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="defaultSelectListItemTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Content="{Binding Value}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Margin="12,0,0,0"
                   Foreground="Black"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Please suggest, how can I use CheckBox.IsChecked property here to get the selected items and show in textblock.

**Update**

```
myList.SelectionChanged += (sender1, args1) =>
{
    List<ILOOKUP> selectedLookup = lookupList.SelectedItems.OfType<ILOOKUP>().ToList();
    textBlock.Text=string.Join(",", selectedLookup.Select(lookup => lookup.I_LU_ANSWER).ToList());
    checkBoxFlyout.Hide();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView already have checkbox in ItemContainerStyle so you shouldn't use another checkbox in DataTemplate. Instead of that you should retemplte ItemContainerStyle make this checkbox standout, to get selected items `MyListBox.SelectedItems`

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListBox" SelectionMode="Multiple" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Yes, i tried without adding checkbox also, but on what event I can get the ListView.SelectedItems?

Comment: Wire up SelectionChanged event

Comment: I did that but it took only one item, not multiple

Comment: Add this SelectionMode="Multiple" to ListView

Comment: I have already done that. Please check my updated code of selectionChanged Event.